# Perl regex to remove invalid html tags from string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like:

```
<div>[CODE]<br />test1</div>
<div>test2</div>
<div>test3</div>
<div>test4<br />[/CODE]</div>
```

When parsing using regex below:

```
$text =~ s#\[CODE\](.+?)\[\/CODE\]#<div>Code:</div><pre class="prettyprint">$1</pre>#isg;
```

it returns string within `<pre>` tag with some closed and some start but not closed div like below

```
<div><div>Code:</div><pre class="prettyprint"><br />test1</div>
<div>test2</div>
<div>test3</div>
<div>test4<br /></pre></div
```

I want to remove all invalid html tags from `<pre>` tag that are closed but not started or started but not closed.

It should return like below:

```
<div><div>Code:</div><pre class="prettyprint"><br />test1
<div>test2</div>
<div>test3</div>
test4<br /></pre></div
```

Comment: The first regex you show is not parsing, it's substituting. You shouldn't try to parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1848654

Comment: This is a tricky one though. How will your program know which tags are wrong? It's not a trivial problem.

Comment: What should happen with `A [CODE] B <!-- B [/CODE] C --> D`?

Comment: What should happen with `<form action="hi?data[CODE]=42"><textarea name="t">[/CODE]</textarea></form>`?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot hope to achieve what you want to achieve in a simplistic manner. Others have gone to great lengths to clean up invalid HTML, but the results are not always what they wanted.

You can try using [tidyp](http://www.tidyp.com/), or install [Alien::Tidyp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::Tidyp) and [HTML::Tidy](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Tidy). Or, even explore what [Marpa](https://jeffreykegler.github.io/Ocean-of-Awareness-blog/individual/2012/html_fmt.html) has to offer.

But, no, you cannot use a simple regex substitution to fix arbitrarily bad HTML.